# Trying to return sum (group by) results from one of two columns depending on value in a 3rd column

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have a table in DB2 (IBM Spectrum Protect) that I am trying to pull a report that has a server name in ENTITY if its a normal backup but puts the server name in SUB_ENTITY if its a VM backup. I want to be able to get a complete list that combines the results from the two and then calculate the overall backup amount for X days. While doing this I need to be able to break out the customer code from the VM nodes server_name. My current solution is to pull the data using two different selects and manually combine the data.

I tried a select with a case but the group by is returning errors.

```
select -
   varchar(ACTIVITY_DETAILS,20) as ACTIVITY_DETAILS, -
  case -
   when ACTIVITY_DETAILS='VMware' -
    then -
     varchar(sub_entity,47) -
    else -
     VARCHAR(ENTITY,47) -
   end as CUSTOMER_ID, -
sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 as TOTAL_GB -
from summary_extended -
 where -
 activity in ('BACKUP') -
 and -
 start_time>=(current_timestamp - 30 days)
group by CUSTOMER_ID
```

I'm needing to group by the results of the case but cannot group by CUSTOMER_ID. I get the following

> ANR0162W Supplemental database diagnostic information:  -1:42S22:-206 ([IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0206N  "CUSTOMER_ID" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703
>   ).

Comment: What are all these hyphens in the syntax?  They look erroneous.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, those are continuation characters.  The TSM/IBM Spectrum Protect command line interprets them as continuation characters and it allows the data to be easier understood from a TSM admin side and for those who don't normally understand SQL select flow. (Which it 90% of most TSM admins).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to efine the alias:

```
select varchar(ACTIVITY_DETAILS, 20) as ACTIVITY_DETAILS, 
       customer_id,
       sum(bytes) / (1024*1024*1024) as TOTAL_GB
from (select se.*,
             (case when ACTIVITY_DETAILS = 'VMware'
                   then varchar(sub_entity, 47)
                   else VARCHAR(ENTITY, 47)
              end) as CUSTOMER_ID
      from summary_extended se
     ) se
where activity in ('BACKUP') and
      start_time >= (current_timestamp - 30 days)
group by varchar(ACTIVITY_DETAILS, 20), 
         customer_id;
```

Comment: I got this result

ANR0162W Supplemental database diagnostic information:  -1:42601:-104 ([IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "as" was found following "IVITY_DETAILS , 20 )".  Expected tokens may
include:  "AND".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: @ChadSmall . . . The alias should not have been in the `group by`.